# No Value for JsonArray - Android

Tags: android, json

so I'm trying to make this android widget which is related to league of legends. So this is the Json 
`{"37358058": [
   {
      "queue": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
      "name": "Akali's Assassins",
      "entries": [{
         "leaguePoints": 0,
         "isFreshBlood": false,
         "isHotStreak": false,
         "division": "IV",
         "isInactive": false,
         "isVeteran": true,
         "losses": 136,
         "playerOrTeamName": "Audition",
         "playerOrTeamId": "37358058",
         "wins": 154
      }],
      "tier": "PLATINUM"
   }
]}`

This is my current code from which I'm trying to pull the tier and the division from.

`JSONArray summoner = null;
summoner = json.getJSONArray("37358058");
            JSONObject c = summoner.getJSONObject(0);`

```
        String tier = c.getString("tier");
        String division = c.getJSONObject("entries").getString("division");
```

`

The error I'm receiving is

> No Value for 37358058

I can't seem to figure it out since its clearly populated.

Hope thats enough information.
Thanks

Comment: JavaScript Object Notation

Comment: I know it's full form. I meant what is the `json` in `json.getJSONArray("37358058");` ? What does it contain?

Comment: oh. lol sorry um it pulls the json data from url.
Here is the code.

`JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
 JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);`

I have confirmed the url is correct so that shouldnt be the issue and the JSONParser class I've tried with other json file and it seems to work correctly with another url. The only thing I can think of that might make a difference is https instead of http. Does that make a difference?
Thanks

Comment: I cant seem to find the edit button for my last post but I think I've found the issue. Its with the url being HTTPS instead of HTTP. I got the Json and put it on my localhost webserver and tried from there and it works perfectly. This only concludes that HTTPS is the problem now :3

Answer (score 1):

To get division you have to do this

```
JSONArray entriesArray=c.getJSONArray("entries");
JSONObject entries=entriesArray.getJSONObject(0);
String division =entries.getString("divsion");
```

Comment: Oh alright thanks. But I still am getting the No Value Error which is stopping everything else to go through like the tier + division :3.